# Cannot delete old AWS IAM Role

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm cleaning up some very old AWS IAM roles and I am unable to delete this one (probably from old tutorial I was following from ACloudguru circa 2018).

I'm confused b/c I'm unable to find the resource.

The resource indicates in one region (`eu-north-1`) and lists using the naming of the region I normally work in (`ca-central-1`).

I did delete a CodeStar project and some SNS in `ca-central-1` and deleted it but still unable to delete this role.

Does this take a few hours or days to delete a Codestar project across all the regions?
Is there another reason why is `eu-north-1` listing the resources?
What am I missing?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Per the [Using service-linked roles for AWS CodeStar Notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dtconsole/latest/userguide/using-service-linked-roles.html) documentation:

> To delete a service-linked role, you must first delete its related resources. This protects your AWS CodeStar Notifications resources because you can't inadvertently remove permission to access the resources.

Comment: I had to expand the Policy dropdown and sure enough there was an Amazon Event Bridge attached.

Comment: Still unable to delete role. :(

Comment: If all dependent resources have been deleted and you've waited a while, say 10 minutes, and retried and it still fails but now it shows you zero dependent resources then I'd recommend an AWS support ticket.

Comment: Is it possible I cannot delete this b/c it's a "Service-linked role"?

Comment: I don't think so. That's a supported operation. You might want to review the awscli documentation for [delete-service-linked-role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/delete-service-linked-role.html). It might help you understand what, if any, active sessions or resources are in use by the role.